# ASP.NET Web Pages, WebForms or MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am thinking about using on of the technologies mentioned in the title but I can't decide which one would be the best for me. I jsut looked at asp.net to get an idea of each technology but I think I need a mix of MVC and WebForms, so that is why I am asking..

- I want the MVC structure in the app itself and in the URLs
- I want easily create a gridview with paging and sorting and easily map it to an SQL Database
- I want to style everything easily via CSS

After I looked at asp.net I think MVC3 would be great for me but I need this in combination with WebForms, as I saw the DataGridView Control will be the best choice for my gridview.

Does someone give me some ideas what the best might be for me ?

After a long time using PHP and HTML/JS I hate it to doe every little step and using precreated Controls I only need to map to a database and customize via css would be a great enhancement to speed development things up!

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [ASP.NET WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) for grids with paging, sorting, etc in MVC3.

Comment: This question is answered already:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/837831/1135871

http://stackoverflow.com/q/2236364/1135871
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should opt for MVC 3 approach (given most of your points mentioned) combined with jQuery DataTables. This gives you a best of both worlds - a great data visualiser and all the advantages of MVC 3.

DataTables
http://datatables.net/

DataTables ASP.NET MVC 3 Tutorial on CodeProject
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Additionally if you didn't want to use the jQuery Data Tables you could look into MVC 3 Web grid which is the built in DataGridView equivalent for MVC:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC, with aspx, Where you can also use the webforms features that you wished for. 
I know there can be a flame war about this, people would suggest different suggestions.

Go for what you want.

All of what you need is possible easily in ASP.NET MVC.